# UITableView, UILabel text color not changing while selecting row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uilabel

I  have `UITableView`, I have four labels with text (white colour) in `UITableView`, when I select rows I want to change label `textcolor` in `blackColor`.

Answer (score 1):

Without your code it is very hard to say that where was you wrong ? But I putting my logic here

First give tag of each `UILabel` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` such like,

```
lbl1.tag = 101;
lbl2.tag = 102;
.
.
.
```

And then

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tv didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101]; // you can get label like
    [label setTextColor:RedColor]; // set as you want
    .
    .
    // write for each label

}
```

And also set it color as it is when your cell is deselected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:101]; // you can get label like
    [label setTextColor:RedColor]; // set color as it is
    .
    .
    .
    // write for each label
}
```

Comment: i created only one uilabel with tag as indexpath.row but its not working

Comment: @RameshKumar - Then just follow me.

Comment: Yes I think this tag thing will work as the label is inside the cell...

Comment: @iPatel i tried its not working

Comment: @RameshKumar - then put your code here. Or have you change `[cell viewWithTag:101]` to `[cell viewWithTag:indexPath.row]` ?

Comment: while tableview scrolling label text is overwrite, is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` tableView delegate method :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      // Change your text color here.
}
```

Comment: i have tried its changing only in last row

Comment: Get your selected cell with tag or indexPath and change it.

Answer (score 0):

In `CellForRowAtIndexPath`, use below code :

**selection :**

```
label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

**normal :**

```
label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: its not working in tableview selecting

Comment: then you need to play with selected index in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and change the text color of UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `textColor` of the `UILabel` is `blackColor`. How did your label's `textColor` changed to `whiteColor`?

Anyways, you can change your label's `textColor` like this:

```
label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

All the best!!!

Comment: i created uilabel and its textcolor then addsubview to cell.contentview now i'm trying to change color in didselectrow but its not changing, only color change appear in last row from any row selecting